# Pair Apple remote and MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, apple-remote-desktop

I am unable to pair my Apple Remote, which otherwise works perfectly, with my MacBook Pro.

My Mac responds to all the commands but the pairing one (I hold menu and next for about five seconds, but nothing happens).

How can I get my Mac and my remote paired?

I am running Mountain Lion, but I don't know if it is relevant to my issue.

I even tried the [digital camera test](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1722#digitaltest) and, when I press the two keys together, after some seconds in which no signal is sent I can see a blinking light.
Is that ok? Or should I be able to see the blinking light right immediately when I press the two buttons?

Answer (score 1):

I would try two things:

First, make sure the battery in the remote is good.  I know this may sound obvious, but I always try to make sure there are no issues with power or connectivity.

Second, go into System Preferences-->Security & Privacy, and click the lock at the bottom to unlock the "Advanced..." button.

Make sure the last checkbox ("Disable remote control infrared receiver") is unchecked.  Then click the pair button.

It will ask you to do the same procedure as before (holding menu and next buttons until you see the paired-remote graphic on the screen).  I know you already tried holding the buttons, but maybe you'll have better luck at the pairing prompt.

Hope this helps.  Best of luck and happy holidays!

Comment: My remote works perfectly apart from pairing. The battery should be good, or am I missing something?

Comment: And the ir receiver is obviously turned on, my Mac receives other commands. However I double checked and it is enabled

Answer (score 1):

Remote pairing works by registering your remote "ID" in the /Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleIRController.plist file, under the UIDFilter key.

There are likewise two pairing commands, one increments the ID by one (thus breaking a previous pairing) and the other one doesn't. On my older model (white) remote the former is Menu+center, the other is Menu+right.

The application iRedLite appears to be bundled with an ID finder, as seen in http://www.filewell.com/iRedLite/downloads/iRL-AppleRemoteIDs.pdf.